# Ignore a single unlisted exception in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, exception, xna, xna-4.0

I want to ignore the exception Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.NoAudioHardwareException in Microscoft Visual Studio 2010. "Ignore" meaning that this particular exception should not cause the debugger to stop (break).

However, it is not listed under Debug->Exceptions. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are an infinite number of possible exception types.  The dialog is pre-populated with only the common exceptions types, the ones that can be raised by the .NET Framework.  It doesn't know beans about exceptions in XNA assemblies.

Simply click the Add button.  Change Type to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".  Type the *full* name of the exception type in the Name box.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!