# All exception settings are unchecked still some exceptions get thrown and debugging stops

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

In visual Studio, I have unchecked all the Exceptions in "Exception Settings"

[image: Image of Exception Settings]

"Enable Just My Code" is checked in Debugging General Options

[image: Image of Enable Just My Code]

Still some Exceptions get thrown
**EXCEPTION DETAILS**

There is an option "Break when this exception type is user-unhandeled" and it is "checked"

[image: Image of Exception Which Comes]

The Exception was originally thrown at the call stack

[External Code]

I don't want the debugging to stop even though the exceptions come (for the time being), so I unchecked the box of "Break when this exception type is user-unhandeled".
But after some hours some other user unhandeled exceptions comes. Are there some settings which can be changed so that the exceptions dont need to be unchecked manually.

What settings are being missed that the "Break when this exception type is user-unhandeled" is "checked".

Comment: Please, I have spent so much time figuring out how this issue can be resolved. If you want to dislike atleast tell the reason

Comment: Why don't you put try/catch then if you don't want the debugging to stop?

Comment: I tried adding try catch but even after that the exception comes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998566/unhandled-exception-in-try-catch

Comment: You need this.[Simply click the Add button. Change Type to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". Type the full name of the exception type in the Name box.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34618762/16764901). Type in all the errors you find, and it won't be triggered the second time.

Comment: Thankyou very much @Jiale Xue

Comment: @Riya Does it work? Or it solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the Image you haven't unchecked the box for `Break when this exception type is thrown` Uncheck that box also to get over with it.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. I took the screenshot before uncheking the box. In the question I did mention about it "I don't want the debugging to stop even though the exceptions come (for the time being), so I unchecked the box of "Break when this exception type is user-unhandeled". Even after that some other exception gets thrown after hours of the job running and I again have to uncheck it, so I need to spend a lot of time monitoring as I can't let the job stop as data will be lost. So I was asking if some options can be changed so that this manual effort can be reduced

Comment: Is there a way that I don't have to wait for the exception to occur and can set it to unchecked in advance